# Regex to View Pages Containing Any Word from a List

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I need to return a Google Analytics Behavior report for pages filtered by any page that contains a word from a list.

In the Advanced Filter, I tried the Containing filter with pipes to separate the words.

```
Include > Page > Containing > apple|orange|grape
```

but that returned all pages and did not filter anything.

Then I tried a Regex approximation to include one or more instances of any part of the word.

```
Include > Page > Regex > apple|orange|grape
Include > Page > Regex > (apple?|orange?|grape?)
Include > Page > Regex > (?:apple|orange|grape)
```

No results.

The regex should match any page URL that contains any of the words in the list. Plural and partial hits should be included. The folder directory is variable. I'm looking for any page that contains the word anywhere.

> - [www.example.com/apple](http://www.example.com/apple)
> - [www.example.com/my-apples](http://www.example.com/my-apples)
> - [www.example.com/something-variable-apples-and-oranges](http://www.example.com/something-variable-apples-and-oranges)
> - [www.example.com/deals-on-apples](http://www.example.com/deals-on-apples) [www.example.com/category/oranges](http://www.example.com/category/oranges)
> - [www.example.com/orange](http://www.example.com/orange) [www.example.com/some/other/directory/oranges](http://www.example.com/some/other/directory/oranges)
> - [www.example.com/test/grape](http://www.example.com/test/grape)
> - etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration:

```
Include > Page > Containing > apple|orange|grape
```

You say it returns you all results but in theory **none should come back**.

This configuration:

```
Include > Page > Regex > apple|orange|grape
```

**It does what you want**, which is to return URLs that contain `apple` and/or `orange` and/or `grape`.

So check that the setting is indeed this.

[EDIT]

Note: there is a data lenght field limit to 256 characters in a Filter pattern.

Comment: Is there a character limit for the filter? When I do a few words, it does work. However, I have a list that is 354 characters long and that is when it seems to break. I noticed it puts all the kewords in the URL so perhaps I am hitting the query string parameter limit with all of the other params in there.

Comment: Yes, there is a limit. I updated my answer.